# How do I pass a list of 'allowed' IDs to filter a Lucene search?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, filtering

I need to return just the documents that a user has access to from a Lucene search. I can get a list of IDs from a database that make up the 'allowed' subset. How can I pass these to Lucene? The articles I've found on the web suggest I need to use a BitSet and FieldCache (am I right?), but I'm having trouble finding good examples. Does anyone have any?

I'm using C#, but any language would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I knew I needed to use a custom filter, asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079934/how-do-you-implement-a-custom-filter-with-lucene-net) got the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to build a MultiPhraseQuery with an array of all the matching IDs, via `MultiPhraseQuery.add(Term[] terms)`.  You can build one of these things with thousands of terms, and Lucene (as always) performs extremely well.

Comment: This seemed promising, but when using "thousands" of terms I hit the maxClauseCount of 1024 (by default). I know I can increase this, but I was hoping that under the hood MultiPhraseQuery wouldn't actually split up into thousands of different clauses. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: OK, I ended up solving this by using a FieldCacheTermsFilter.