# Lucene.NET 2.9 Custom Filter to add authorisation

Tags: c#, search, filter, lucene, lucene.net

Friends,

I'm new to Lucene...
I successfully created an index, added fields, I could search etc it works.

Now, I've in my database a view that tell which users can see which document. This view is created using several complicated rules so I want to reuse the view. So I need to add a filter in Lucene search to remove documents that match the query but the users doesn't have access to.
What I tried to do now is:
- Store the db document id in a field. It's a Guid, I store it as a string.
- create a custom filter that fetch all document id the current user can access, then filter using the field in lucene

I've the feeling that it'll not be efficient... User can have access to hundred of thousands documents, so I may retrieve 200 000 document Id I need to filter on.
I suppose I've to cache some stuff...
Here is the code I've writen, but it doesn't work: no document are returned when the filter is used (it should return 3 docs)

```
public class LuceneAuthorisationFilter : Filter
{
    public override DocIdSet GetDocIdSet(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader reader)
    {
        List<Guid> ids = this.load(); // Load list of ID from database
        OpenBitSet result = new OpenBitSet(reader.MaxDoc);

        int[] docs = new int[1];
        int[] freq = new int[1];

        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
        {
            Lucene.Net.Index.TermDocs termDocs = reader.TermDocs(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("EmId", ids.ElementAt(i).ToString()));

            int count = termDocs.Read(docs, freq);
            if (count == 1)
            {
                result.FastSet(docs[0]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on what's wrong ? And how to increase perf ?

Thank you

EDIT:
The code above works, the problem was only that the EmId field was not indexed. Now I've changed and it works.
**Now I would like to have any tip to improve performances**

---

***2ND EDIT TO ADD FEEDBACK***

Note: The test environment contains 25 000 documents, and the  list of document access contains 50 000 id (because all documents are not yet

indexed)

- Using the custom filter above: ~2600ms the 1st time, 2100ms the next times as filter is cached
- Using a Boolean query filter: ~4700ms then ~4000ms

These are poor performances ... So I've searched again an found 'FieldCacheTermsFilter' filter.

- Using a FieldCacheTermsFilter: ~600ms then ~60ms

This is acceptable performance

PS: I also found another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795532/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-allowed-ids-to-filter-a-lucene-search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about performances is always tricky when no numbers/measurements are given.

That being said, what have you benched in terms of performances? What are your bottlenecks (IO/CPU/etc) and have you compared it against other methods?

Do you actually need to improve performance? Discussions about perfomance improvements are not about "feelings", they are around hard facts based on evidence and a need to improve.

Now for your `Filter`, unless theres something I didnt get from the question, I dont see why you cannot use what is already build into Lucene to do the hard work.

Here is how I usually handle permission stuff in Lucene, it always worked well with indexes containing billions of documents. I usually use LRU type caches with a minimum age for an items to be purged off the cache.

IE: cache 100 items, but cache more if the least recently used is not more than 15 minutes old.

If you try something like this, it could be interesting if you compare it to your method and come back to post some performance numbers.

**Disclaimer**: code written directly in the textarea of SO, take it more as pseudo-code than an already working copy paste solution:

```
// todo: probably some thread safety
public class AccessFilterFactory
{
    private static AccessFilterFactory _instance = new AccessFilterFactory();;
    private AccessFilterFactory()
    {
    }

    public AccessFilterFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Cache<int, Filter> someKindaCache = new Cache<int, Filter> ();

    // gets a cached filter if already built, if not it creates one
    // caches it and returns it
    public Filter GetFilterForUser(int userId)
    {
        // return from cache if you got it
        if(someKindaCache.Exists(userId))
            return someKindaCache.Get(userId);

        // if not, build and cache it
        BooleanQuery filterQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        foreach(string id in ids)
        {
            filterQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("EmId", id)),  BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        }
        Filter cachingFilter = new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(filterQuery));
        someKindaCache.Put(userId, cachingFilter);
        return cachingFilter;
    }

    // removes a new invalid filter from cache (permissions changed)
    public void InvalidateFilter(int userId)
    {
        someKindaCache.Remove(userId);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You're right about the "feeling" of performances. I didn't post any numbers because I don't have it yet. And I also don't have "other methods" to test for better performance. I was expecting what you posted: different way to reach the same functionality, so I can try and choose what's best. And any other tips from experience you have gathered. For example, using a BooleanQuery with 200 000 term will be efficient ? The problem is that to answer to this question, I need to write the code and test. If someone already know this answer, it could save me a lot of time. Thank you for your post

Comment: I dont know, that would need to be tested. The one I currently can get numbers for does it for a few thousands (2k-4k terms). My documents are grouped into security categories and thats what I filter on for access.

Comment: Just some feedback: the BooleanQuery accept max 1024 terms by default. This can be changed using static property 'BooleanQuery.MaxClauseCount'. But using a boolean query with 25000 terms is 2x slower than the filter I wrote in my question. Using a cache on the 'Filter' reduce the search time by 20%

Answer (score 0):

For me it is look like arcitectural challange:

- you are using user base access for documets. When there is table/index where you contains mapping between document id and user id. It is good and should works well for relations database but not for documents base database.
- for document base database, as lucene - you are working with set of documents and according to your issue /description/ you are trying to hide documents based on another document set. This is possible but - as you see there is issue with performance.
- according to my experience is better to add extra column/field into documents index itself. Lucene is good in working with one set of data.

I see following approach. Documents index should be extended with 4 extra fields:

- allowed for users  [allow-user]
- blocked for users  [deny-user]
- allowed for groups [allow-role]
- blocked for groups [deny-role]

Then each document before store into the index (during indexing) should be processed by extra code which indicate document permission from you database table.. .like you did already:

```
List<Guid> ids = this.load(); // Load list of ID from database
```

this code should investigate list of roles which must be blocked, which must have access (better approach to use roles instead of particular user) and individual users - when it is setup per user base (which user should or shouldn't have access).

So idea is simple: "is better to do job ones",- before store document you can prepare such information (i think you knew that one field could contains few values in one document)

Last thing - during search you need to prepare universal filter (boolenquery), with 4 subfilters:

- current userid should be in a list of allow [allow-user]
- but userid should not be in [deny-user]
- and userroles should not be in [deny-roles]
- and userroles should not be in [deny-roles]

Comment: and you existing variant also could be improved:
   each document in lucene has identifier (integer or long) this id you can use (pre-cache) to filterout document from search result. it is hard, resource consuming but possible.

Answer (score 0):

for lucene.net 4.8 it can looks following:

- hit collector can contains "distinct value filter" (it is insode combined filter).
- during setnext reader "distinct value filter" is able to pre-process terms data
- durring collecting (method collect) filter is checking that document has unique data in field
- [image: List item]
- Filtering itself can looks following:
- [image: List item]
- and distinctValueFilter source code is:

```html
public class DistinctValuesFilter
{
    private void InitDuplicatesContext(AtomicReaderContext context, ISearchRequest request)
    {
        var ireader = context.AtomicReader;
        var terms = ireader.GetTerms(request.DistinctBy);
        if (terms == null) return;
        var termsEnum = terms.GetEnumerator();

        DocsEnum? docsEnum = null;
        string termTxt;
        while (termsEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            termTxt = termsEnum.Term.ToString();
            int termIndex = -1;
            if (readerIdx > 0)
            {
                termIndex = knownTerms.IndexOf(termTxt);
                if (termIndex > -1) termIndex = termIndex + 1; //zero is not possible, it is using as another purpouse 
            }
            if (termIndex < 0)
            {
                knownTerms.Add(termTxt);
                termIndex = knownTerms.Count;
            }
            if (termsEnum.DocFreq > 0)
            {
                docsEnum = termsEnum.Docs(ireader.LiveDocs, docsEnum, DocsFlags.NONE);
                while (docsEnum.NextDoc() < DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS)
                {
                    var dinx = docsEnum.DocID;
                    if (docTerms[dinx] > 0)
                    {
                        var mt = docMTerms[dinx];
                        if (mt == null) docMTerms[dinx] = mt = new HashSet<int>();
                        if (!mt.Contains(termIndex))
                            mt.Add(termIndex);
                    }
                    docTerms[dinx] = termIndex;
                };
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDistinct(int docIndex)
    {
        var termIndex = docTerms[docIndex];
        if (termIndex == 0) return true;//document has no term in such field
        if (alreadyUsedTerms.FastGet(termIndex)) return false;
        alreadyUsedTerms.FastSet(termIndex);
        return true;
    }

    public void SetNextReader(AtomicReaderContext context, ISearchRequest request)
    {
        var dlength = context.AtomicReader.NumDocs;
        docTerms = new int[dlength];//init collection of documents that contains flag- index of related term
        docMTerms = new HashSet<int>[dlength];
        //unfortunatelly terms are not unique per index, they are uniq per segment- so we have to re-construct that
        InitDuplicatesContext(context, request);
        readerIdx++;
    }


    private int readerIdx = 0;  

    /// <summary>
    /// collection of known terms with duplicates (few related documents)
    /// </summary>
    private HashSet<string> knownTerms;
    /// <summary>
    /// contains term index per each document number
    /// </summary>
    private int[] docTerms;
    private HashSet<int>[] docMTerms;//not realized yet: multiple terms docs
    private OpenBitSetDISI alreadyUsedTerms;

    public DistinctValuesFilter(int docsLength)
    {           
        knownTerms = new HashSet<string>(docsLength);//init collection of terms which possible has duplicates

        docTerms = new int[0];//init collection of documents that contains flag- index of related term
        docMTerms = new HashSet<int>[0];
        this.alreadyUsedTerms = new OpenBitSetDISI(docsLength);
    }
}
```

idea of it:

- problem that different segments can have duplicates in terms
- to solve that - hashset of terms for entire index is collection
- during setnextreader we are able to get documents those related to known terms.
- during "ismatch" we have to find document terms (in array of itegers where each index is document id and value - is term index in hashset). And have to remeber that such term is used, so next time we don't need to investigate that.